# Find the GCC Version

Tags: gcc, autoconf, automake

Using autoconf/automake how does one find the GCC version on the system?

To get the python version installed you'd use AM_PATH_PYTHON, and then the PYTHON_VERSION variable would be available. Is there something similar for the GCC version?

(Also, is it possible to get the major, minor and patch level of gcc?)

Comment: What will you do if gcc is not even installed?

Comment: Cry. Personally I'm not supporting non-gcc compilers (and in the physics community I don't think that's a big problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search reveals the [ax_gcc_version](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_gcc_version.html) macro which should give you the `GCC_VERSION` variable.

Unfortunately, that macro depends on `AX_GCC_OPTION` which has recently been [deprecated in favour of](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf-archive.git;a=commitdiff;h=4593960ff5726a41d3cdb7e3b3ee198cab6f5983) of `AX_*_CHECK_FLAG`.

This [mailing list post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf-archive-maintainers/2011-07/msg00015.html) suggests a patch for `ax_gcc_version` which amounts to:

```
AC_DEFUN([AX_GCC_VERSION], [
  GCC_VERSION=""
  AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-dumpversion],
     [ax_gcc_version_option=yes],
     [ax_gcc_version_option=no])

  AS_IF([test "x$GCC" = "xyes"],[
    AS_IF([test "x$ax_gcc_version_option" != "xno"],[
      AC_CACHE_CHECK([gcc version],[ax_cv_gcc_version],[
        ax_cv_gcc_version="`$CC -dumpversion`"
        AS_IF([test "x$ax_cv_gcc_version" = "x"],[
          ax_cv_gcc_version=""
        ])
      ])
      GCC_VERSION=$ax_cv_gcc_version
    ])
  ])
  AC_SUBST([GCC_VERSION])
])
```

I have not tested this, but it looks sensible.

---

> (Also, is it possible to get the major, minor and patch level of gcc?)

Once you have the version string in `GCC_VERSION`, you can manually split the string to get the major, minor and patch versions. Here's a simple-minded solution:

```
GCC_VERSION_MAJOR=$(echo $GCC_VERSION | cut -d'.' -f1)
GCC_VERSION_MINOR=$(echo $GCC_VERSION | cut -d'.' -f2)
GCC_VERSION_PATCH=$(echo $GCC_VERSION | cut -d'.' -f3)
```

Comment: I have a question: why would you need to cache the value in `ax_cv_gcc_version` and then set it `GCC_VERSION` to it?I