# how to use macro __GNUC__ and __GNUC_MINOR__ in configure.ac

Tags: c, gcc, macros, autoconf

I need to test the version of gcc in configure.ac, then I do this:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ > 3) 
    CFLAGS = xxxx　　
#else 
    CFLAGS = xxxx
#endif
```

but this failed, the CFLAGS in if expression is never used, and the gcc i'm using now is 4.1.2.
Then I wrote a simple c program to print out the `__GNUC__  __GNUC_MINOR__`, it works very well.
did I miss something? how can I use the two macros in configure.ac?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the GCC Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067385/find-the-gcc-version)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how autoconf works. `autoconf.ac` is not a C file that gets processed by the C preprocessor. Autoconf macros are something entirely different. You should look for a tutorial. If I remember correctly, [this is a decent one](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html). (Somebody will surely comment if it isn't :)

To check whether the compiler supports a particular flag, you should use the `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` macro from [the Autoconf Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/).

Answer (score 0):

`CFLAGS` is [reserved](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Preset-Output-Variables) as an environment variable by the autotools. `./configure --help` lists some others. Ideally, the user should supply the appropriate compiler flags, e.g.,

```
CC="gcc -std=c99" CFLAGS="-pipe -Wall -pedantic -O2" ./configure
```

and it's entirely reasonable to have a `README` file with the package if there are issues with different compilers. The best *modern* tutorial I'm aware of is the [Autotools Mythbuster](https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/).

Now, if you want to proceed with this anyway as an interim solution, it is *possible* to modify `CFLAGS`...

```
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
  [[#if defined (__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ > 3)
    #error "GCC4" /* not an actual error - just using the fail condition. */
    #endif]])],
  [CFLAGS=<your non-GCC4 flags here>], [CFLAGS=<your GCC4 flags here>])
```

If *adding* options to `CFLAGS`, this can be done with automake's `CFLAGS` primary - but that's another answer in itself.

Comment: That won't actually work reliably -- clang and Intel's compiler also define __GNUC__, but they don't accept the same command line options as GCC.

Comment: @pdw - No, it's not reliable. But clang and icc share enough flags and C language extensions with gcc that it *might* work for the more common switches. And besides, it's what the OP asked for.